# Parsing commas in field with TextFieldParser causes extra column

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

Following on a previous thread [Object reference on array with regex.replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570447/object-reference-on-array-with-regex-replace)

I have few columns in `cpath` which contain fields such as `street,""test,format"", casio` . Unfortunately,

```
csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
```

adds empty extra columns to the `DataTable` `csvData` because of the comma between `test and format`. Hence the the following interrogation:

Does a trick exist to remove the comma from `"""test,format"""` so as to get `street,""test format"", casio` in `csvData`?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

```
private static List<string[]> RemoveComaDataFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
    {
        List<string[]> allLineFields = new List<string[]>();

        try
        {
            using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(csv_file_path))
            using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
            {
                csvReader.Delimiters=new[] { "," };
                csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                {

                    string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                    string pattern = "\"";
                    string replacement = "";
                    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
                    //Making empty value as null
                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        //Remove quotation marks on Fields
                        fieldData[i] = Regex.Replace(fieldData[i], pattern, replacement);
                        if (fieldData[i] == "")
                        {
                            fieldData[i] = null;
                        }
                    }
                    //csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                    allLineFields.Add(fieldData);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return allLineFields;
    }
```

Comment: `TextFieldParser` has a property `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` which you should set to `true`. Then the comma in `"test,format"` doesn't matter. You should also show the code that generates the `DataTable`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: because i receive csv `data` containing the `coma delimiter` and unfortunately i cannot change it. however i've never expected that some fields could contain `,` messing everything up. so I am really stuck...

Comment: Have you read the rest of my comment ;) `TextFieldParser` has no problems with comma if the field is wrapped in quotes

Comment: @dark.vador Did you try the flag? If the comma is *not* quoted, it *is* a new column. If a field *is* quoted, it shouldn't matter whether it contains a comma or not

Answer (score 2):

`TextFieldParser` has a property [`HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.hasfieldsenclosedinquotes(v=vs.110).aspx) which you should set to `true`. Then the comma in "test,format" doesn't matter because it will be interpreted as a single value.

Example:

```
List<string[]> allLineFields = new List<string[]>();
string sampleLine = @"street,""test,format"", casio";
using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(sampleLine))
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(sr))
{
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
    parser.Delimiters = new[] { "," };
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
        allLineFields.Add(fields);
    }
}
```

Result is a single `string[]` with three fields:

```
    [0] {string[3]}     string[]
    [0] "street"        string
    [1] "test,format"   string
    [2] "casio"         string
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, will try this by hoping it won't have an incidence on function `public static void InsertDataSQLBulkCopy(csvData)` using this `Datable` as argument. Best,

Comment: @dark.vador: could only be  a positive impact if the `DataTable` contains correct data. But i dont know how you generate the `DataTable`, so there might be still an issue.

Comment: sure Tim. Thanks for your promptness and help on this.

Comment: following your suggestion i 've edited the post with function `RemoveComaDataFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)` but the issue is still persisting...

Comment: @dark.vador: so your method reads a csv file and removes additional leading and tralining quotes? You don't need regex, use: `string newData=fieldData[i].Trim().Trim('"'); fieldData[i]=newData.Length==0?null:newData;`. But maybe you need to show your `DataTable` code that has the issue.

Comment: fair enough, thanks Tim for the tip. Unfortunately the the edited method does not read correctly rows from `Main()` (e.g  `Console.WriteLine(allLineFields[192]`), outputting weird `System.String[]` and I was wondering if everything was correct from your suggestion. As i was not familiar with `List` class as opposed to `Datatable`, i will therefore keep working on it...

Comment: @dark.vador: i see another possible issue if your field contains double quotes like `street,""test,format"", casio` as opposed to `street,"test,format", casio`. If that's the case it should throw a `MalformedLineException` which you should handle in the loop. You should never have empty catch blocks since it's just swallowing it, so you won't even recognize that something isn't working as desired.

Comment: sure Tim, was hoping the field could contain a single quote, then i would have been quickly sorted even using a small `VBA macro`: e.g replace `"`, by `'` and keep this as `text` should not have been affected by the delimiter. cheers.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have the similar problem but with a double quote in it. `"EquipDesc[14]","SMU Scanner"Program","PV1500"` Look at the second element. This is the exact csv value I open in notepad. I am using the exact method as in the question but getting `MalFormedLine` exception. Any way to solve this?